# jQuery show() in Chrome on a button

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, show-hide

I have a button which I'm hiding/showing with jQuery, depending if a checkbox is checked or not. This works great in every browser, except Chrome. The button gets the `display: block;` style, but it doesn't appear. If i move the mouse on it, I can see that this button gets `0px` `height` and `width`. I've tried giving the button a fixed size, but it didn't helped (neither if I give a `display: block;` by default). Any ideas?

I need to use the .checbox `div` be cause I'm using [fancy checkbox](http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/). The `input` is `hidden`.

CSS:

```
button {
    background-color: #A01823;
    border: 1px solid #710F12;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    padding: 3px 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click",".enter_chat .checkbox",function() {
    enter_chat();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    enter_chat(true);
});

function enter_chat(init) {
    init = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? init : false;
    if ($("#enter_chat").is(':checked')) {
        $("#btn_enter_chat").hide();
        $("#messaging_view_send_message").keyup(function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                $("#btn_enter_chat").click();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#btn_enter_chat").show();
        $("#messaging_view_send_message").unbind();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="enter_chat">
   <div class="checkbox" style="background-position: 0px 0px;">
      <input id="enter_chat" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="enter_chat" value="1">
      <label>Submit by pressing enter</label>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="messaging_view[submit]" class="btn_comment" id="btn_enter_chat">Send message</button>
```

Comment: Can you give us the html for the button as well?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've Updated my post!

Comment: Thanks - managed to replicate and fix your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the document.ready code to this...

```
$(document).on("click","#enter_chat",function() {
    enter_chat();
});
```

See this working example...

http://jsfiddle.net/ESfTv/

Answer (score 0):

I have used following code in html along with your all other script and it works fine in all browsers also in chrome

```
<pre>
    <input type="checkbox" class="enter_chat" id="enter_chat" checked="checked"/>
    <button type="submit" name="messaging_view[submit]" class="btn_comment" id="btn_enter_chat"> Send message </button>
```

I suggest you to right click on chrome browser and click **inspect element** then see Console for errors if any...
Also for firefox use **firebug** always

Comment: I'm using and didn't got any errors, that is the problem. I checked the HTML during clicking the checkbox and it was doing what it must do, but I don't get it, where does it get the 0px height and width.